# My while loop is keeps looping. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

In this the total amount is the amount the user need to pay. If user pay lesser than the total amount the system needs to subtract the payment and show their balance and keep on looping until the payment is completed. But, when I run my codes its keep on looping while showing the balance.

```
print ("Your total amount is:", total_amount)
print ("")

payment = int(input("Please insert your payment: "))

count = 0
    
while payment != total_amount:
    count = total_amount - payment
    print ("Your balance:", count)
    payment = int(input("Please insert your payment: "))

if payment == total_amount:
    print ("Successful")
```

Comment: change `payment != total_amount` to `payment <= total_amount` to stop your loop and add a condition which would make sure you are not adding more payment than total_amount

Comment: You're not reducing `total_amount` in the loop...

Answer (score 0):

does the program outputs "Successful" if the user inputs the total amount on the first input?

if the user doesnt input the total amount on the first input, what could happen is that the variable named payment will never be equal to the total payment, but the count will eventually reach the total amount yes, but the while loop does not has variable count working is logic statement, it uses payment as the variable for its logic.  if someones buys a something from a store, and the total is 5 dollars,, and the buyer has 1 dollar bills, the buyer will first put one dollar on the counter, then the other 1, and so on... but the buyer will not put 1 dollar on the counter, and then 5 dollars on the counter, because that would be 6 dollars

Comment: Okay, but what is should I do to make it work properly?

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating either payment or total_amount correctly in the loop. I believe this should work.

```
payment = int(input("Please insert your payment: "))

while payment <= total_amount:
    diff = total_amount - payment
    print("Your balance:", diff)
    payment += int(input("Please insert your payment: "))

if payment == total_amount:
    print("Successful")
```

Comment: Even when I made the payment completely. It keeps looping the "Your Balance:" statement.

Comment: That makes sense. Sorry it should be < in the loop condition.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, only if I pay the correct amount in one go, should I successfully pay. Of course this is wrong. I have modified and added some details to your code like this:

```py
print("Your total amount is: $%.2f \n" % (total_amount)) 
count = 0

while count < total_amount:
    payment = int(input("Please insert your payment: $"))
    count += payment
    print ("Your balance: $%.2f" % (total_amount - count))

print("Successful")
if count > total:
    print("Your change is $%.2f" % (count - total))
```